# EE1.x and EE2.x sites side-by-side?

Tags: ee2-upgrades, image-galleries

I'm wanting to update my site (which has blogs for me, my wife, our dogs as well as discussion forums on home cheese making and extensive image galleries on wild mushrooms and wildflowers of Colorado high country) to EE2.x.

I've tested this update offline and I think most of it will go well. We'll lose some functionality, but I've found replacements or can do without. (Still looking for an "on this day" replacement, see my other post.)

My biggest concern is the loss of the Image Gallery in EE2.x. I have many hundreds of photos archived in three galleries, most with meaningful titles, descriptions and even comments. This gallery has been the source of photos published in books on mushrooms and wildflowers because the images are well documented and easy to find.

Sure, I could migrate all of the photos to Flickr or maintain them natively in EE with Matrix, but that would mean manually moving hundreds and hundreds of photos and duplicating titles and descriptions, and likely losing the valuable comments.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to keep my EE1.x gallery "live" and available, while also moving the blogs to EE2.x.

Here is my thinking: create a new database and migrate EE1.x to that database and upgrade to EE2.x. Have my "main" site be EE2.x driven, but provide links to the old blog galleries still running under EE1.x.

Has anyone tried anything like this and what would you suggest as the way to manage the two sides in a single domain? (Root-level directory structure, how to set up index and path files, etc.?)

Of course, all this would be unnecessary if there was Image Gallery support in EE2.x. And, it has been rumored for a long time. Anyone know anything about that possibility?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used EE1's Gallery feature for years now, so unfortunately my memory of this is hazy, but even in the EE1 days I felt Matrix just worked better for galleries.

You could look at using the excellent [Datagrab module](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab):  for importing into a channel with the images going into the matrix field. I expect you'd be able to make a template in EE1 that would output the info as XML ready for importing.

Also worth checking out Pixel & Tonic's Assets for running galleries - I believe Datagrab can import into this as well.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'll look into it. I don't have a lot of experience with Matrix but I see how I might be able to create a link to the image and "grab" the title and description for each from an XML file. Not sure how I'd handle the comments in a matrix row, but may be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Managing EE1 and EE2 sites on same domain might cause you some pain.

I would suggest switching from Gallery to [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/). It [looks like](http://www.devdemon.com/forums/viewthread/636/) there's a version for EE 1.x available. And it is [possible](http://www.devdemon.com/forums/viewthread/2137/)  to import existing images to Channel Images gallery (though it could probably still require some manual labour).

Comment: I've never been able to register with the devdemon site to buy and download their products. Even after repeated attempts to email them, my registration and logon attempts fail. Too bad because they have a couple of plugins I could use. What I've done, although quite expensive, is use Importer along with Matrix. I've successfully imported links to the master photos along with titles and captions. And, I'm working on templates that mimic the EE Gallery presentation. I don't have comments working yet. And, I won't import the old comments. But, I may have a workable solution till something better.

Comment: If you have troubles buying addons from DevDemon site, you can get them from [devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/developers/devdemon)

Comment: I use channel images and it really does a super job. Brad has always been responsive on any requests I have had and has given me great support. I find it out of sorts that your having issues contacting him.  Lookup @DevDemon on twitter.

Comment: Rick... Email me directly or hit me up at twitter @parscale. I will get you registered on DevDemon. Something must be up with the email that gets sent to you... Also you can always buy at Devot-ee...

Comment: I re-registered on DevDemon with a different email and got in okay. Thanks. You made some $$ off me now!